# Better text UI debugger for C++, like pudb for python

Tags: c++, gdb, gdbserver, gdb-python, pudb

I'm trying to debug a large C++ project on Linux remotely, which is a little difficult to re-build via Visual Studio locally. Therefore I attempt to debug it via console. While, the `gdb` or `gdb --tui` or `gdb-dashboard` tools is not convenient for interaction. I think `pudb` is a tool for python in the term of interaction. Therefore, are there any better text UI debuggers via console for C++? 
Thanks for telling me the tools or any suggestion, I will really appreciate it!

Comment: What do you consider the most important features of `pudb` that `gdb -tui` is missing? What do you mean it's not convenient for interaction?

Answer (score 0):

pudb is awesome and you can drop into an IPython terminal at any time with the current local variables. You probably won't get that level of interaction in C++ anytime soon. But gdb is very powerful and using the TUI plus some pretty-printers is definitely very usable, even in larger projects.

It helps if you read the documentation and learn some tricks, such as using gdb's [convenience variables](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html). You can store an object in a convenience variable when it is in scope and access it later to check its state using the convenience variable (as long as it still exists).

Using [breakpoint commands](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_node/gdb_34.html) and a `.gdbinit` file with repetitive commands also helps a lot.

If you want to implement [pretty printers](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html) for some of you classes, I think looking at other people's code is a great way to start. [Here](https://github.com/darcamo/gdb_armadillo_helpers) you can see some pretty printers for some classes in the [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) library (used for linear algebra).